# How to make div wrap around content properly (with spacing)?

Tags: html, css, overflow, border, padding

I'm trying to make a div automatically change width based on other content it encounters. It should be straightforward, but my div refuses to be anything less than 100% width. I've tried a number of ways to do this.

Ultimately I'm trying to make the div have a little spacing on the left and right sides (so the border is neater), but the div goes under the other divs.

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve

[image]

What I get (subheader is 100% width and underneath)

I've tried a number of things to fix this, using overflow:hidden, float:left... Nothing does it.

Code below.

```
<div class="box">
<div class="side"></div>
<div class="psubheader">Test</div>
</div>

<style>

.box {
width: 50%;
height: 1000px;
border:1px solid;
}

.psubheader {
    padding-bottom:7px;
    font-family: 'sans-serif';
    font-size: 1.35em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:-10px;
}

.side {
width: 50%;
height: 1000px;
background-color:red;
float:right;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove any `float`'s. Then set `flex` to the parent and define the widths one each flex item. In your version, the `psubheader` had no width defined and was carried into the floated div. What I would do is use a text element (whichever you prefer) and set the border on that element, then restrict the width.

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse;
}

.psubheader {
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  font-family: 'sans-serif';
  font-size: 1.35em;
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a2a9b1;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.side {
  width: 50%;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
}

h5 {
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #a2a9b1;
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="side"></div>
  <div class="psubheader">
    <h5 class="tst">Test</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update your question with a detailed description of the desired result.

Comment: Updated code...

Comment: @Tecior You updated the snippet but didn't update the description of what you want. Perhaps include a markup image that shows the problem.

Comment: Okay, I found the solution. I added margin: 0.5em 0 0.5em 1em to the floated box, and then overflow:hidden to the psubheader. No need for h5.

Comment: @Tecior I suggest next time you ask a question you provide a clear and concise explanation of the current issues and the desired result. The quality of answers you receive is dictated by the quality of the question asked. Happy you found a solution, nonetheless.